# Django ManyToMany Field with field name values

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

[image: ManyToMany Field Coming as object]

## model.py

```
class MedtechProductCategory(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False)
type = models.CharField(choices=type_choices_for_tag, max_length=512)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'medtech_product_category'

class ProductsInfo(models.Model):
deal_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
category = models.ManyToManyField(MedtechProductCategory,  related_name='product_info_category')

class Meta:
    db_table = 'products_info'

def getTags(self):
    return self.category.values_list()
```

## admin.py

```
class ProductsInfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
filter_horizontal = ('category',)
admin.site.register(ProductsInfo, ProductsInfoAdmin)
```

So i want to show the name of the category field in the filter search and want to save them as objects while doing save.

How to customise it to show the name of the manytomany field and on save save the objects of the manytomany field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `__unicode__` method to your model which will return the string that you want to use.

For python 3, use `__str__` instead.

```
# on ProductsInfo model
def __str__(self):
    return self.category.name
```

Comment: which model MedtechProductCategory or ProductsInfo
and what should be added to filter_horizontal ?

Comment: @Gagan it's good practice to include a `__str__` or `__unicode__` method on every model you make. The example above should go on the `ProductsInfo` model. I don't understand the rest of your question.